# [Global variable]Why my variable is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone tell me why I get an undefined MessageList in export function and how to get a correct value?   The two blocks are in a same file.

```
var MessageList;


var sql = require("mssql");

var config = {
//config
};

// connect to your database
sql.connect(config, function (err) {

    if (err) console.log(err);

    var request = new sql.Request();

    request.query('select top 3 * from test', function (err, recordset) {

        if (err) console.log(err)

        MessageList = JSON.stringify(recordset);

        console.log("MessageList in sql.connect:"+MessageList);   //===> that's ok

    });
});
```

The Problem is here:

```
 exports.getMessageList = function (callback) {
 console.log("MessageList in exports:"+MessageList);  // ===> **MessageList here will show undefine**
 callback(MessageList);
 };
```

Comment: The code shown doesn't seem to call `getMessageList()` at all. How do you call it? Are the two blocks of code shown in different files, or...? How are they related to each other?

Comment: You set `MessageList` in a callback that fires once the query finishes. If you call `getMessageList` before that time, `MessageList` will be undefined.